# JavaFX: how to read CurrentTime of MediaPlayer while not in JavaFX App Thread

Tags: javafx

Is there a thread safe way to read properties of the JavaFX `MediaPlayer` (such as `CurrentTime`)?

To play/change a media I typically use `Platform.runLater`, but I need the `CurrentTime` immediately returned.

Is it safe to do `myplayer.getCurrentTime()`? Or will I get into trouble if the `player` is disposed off by another thread?

**EXAMPLE**:

```java
private MediaPlayer player;

public void playMe(){
    Platform.runLater(
        new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            player = new MediaPlayer(media);
            player.play();
    }});
}
public void deleteMe(){
    Platform.runLater(
        new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (player != null) player.dispose();
            player = null;
    }});
}

public Double getCurrentTime(){
    if (player != null) return player.getCurrentTime().toSeconds(); // thread issues???
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please read link above.

Comment: Your link is not relevant - I'm not trying to reproduce a problem.

Comment: You code should be able to be copied. It should also reproduce the problem you are currently experiencing using the least amount of code.

Comment: Your comment is not relevant - I'm not trying to reproduce a problem.

Comment: Make sure you really need to do this.  Do everything on the JavaFX application thread unless you have a very good reason not do so.  That way you don't have to worry about concurrency issues, which you may find difficult to deal with.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. But you _are_ asking for help, and seeing a minimal example of what you're trying to do can influence the contents of a potential answer. For instance, it may be completely unnecessary to use background threads in the first place. Regardless, fabian's answer and the linked duplicate should help you.

Answer (score 4):

JavaFX properties are not thread-safe. Memory consistency is not guaranteed: Java is allowed to create a copy of the memory containing the property object for the background thread at any time. When this happens, any changes to the property happening later won't be visible to the background thread.

It's not too hard to make sure the value is accessible from the thread though. Depending on the frequency of the access and the delay you're willing accept for the information retrieval, the following approaches could work for you:

#### Updating a `AtomicReference` from a listener

This way you simply make sure the updates become visible to the background thread by assigning the value to a `AtomicReference` on the application thread:

```
final AtomicReference<Duration> time = new AtomicReference<>(player.getCurrentTime());
player.currentTimeProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> time.set(newValue));

Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        System.out.println(time.get());
    }
});
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

The drawback is that the updates to the reference happen more often than necessary. (A `volatile` field may do the trick too btw.)

#### Querying the property using `Platform.runLater`

As alternative you could simply schedule a runnable reading the variable using `Platform.runLater`. This approach does not require a reference to be continuously updated:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        CompletableFuture<Duration> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        
        Platform.runLater(() -> future.complete(player.getCurrentTime()));
        try {
            Duration time = future.get(); // get value as soon as evaluated on application thread
            System.out.println(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
});
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

**Note:** for both approaches you need to deal with the fact that you may set the `player` field to `null`. Note that any test is subject to the same memory consistency issues as described at the start of the answer. The first approach would require you to make the field `volatile` to make sure the change is visible to the background thread too, for the second approach you could either cancel the future or throw cause an exception to notify the caller: `future.completeExceptionally` and `future.cancel(true)` result in `future.get()` yielding an `ExecutionException` or a `CancelationException` respecively.